# How to add a record data to this without using apex?

Tags: apex, lightning-aura-components, aura, record

created a static table but now need to add record values to it ? Help me and thanks in advance.
code:

```
<aura:component implements="flexipage:availableForRecordHome,force:hasRecordId,force:lightningQuickAction" access="global">
  <table class="slds-table slds-table_cell-buffer slds-table_bordered slds-table_col-bordered" aria-label="Example table of Opportunities with vertical borders">

    <thead>
<tr class="slds-line-height_reset">
<th class="" scope="col">
<div class="slds-truncate" title="Applicant ID">Applicant ID</div>
</th>
<th class="" scope="col">
<div class="slds-truncate" title="Name of Candidate (as in Passport)">Name of Candidate (as in Passport)</div>
</th>
<th class="" scope="col">
<div class="slds-truncate" title="Job Role (being considered for)">Job Role (being considered for)</div>
</th>
<th class="" scope="col">
<div class="slds-truncate" title="JO No.">JO No.</div>
</th>
<th class="" scope="col">
<div class="slds-truncate" title="Vendor  / Source">Vendor/Source  </div>
</th>
</tr>
</thead>
<tbody>

    
    <tr class="slds-hint-parent">
<td data-label="Applicant ID">
<div class="slds-truncate" > </div>
</td>
<td data-label="Name of Candidate (as in Passport)">
<div class="slds-truncate"> </div>
</td>
<td data-label="Job Role (being considered for)">
<div class="slds-truncate" > </div>
</td>
<td data-label="JO No.">
<div class="slds-truncate"> </div>
</td>
<td data-label="Amount">
<div class="slds-truncate">  </div>
</td>
    </tr>
</tbody>
    </table></aura:component>
```

Comment: What exactly are you trying to do? How can we help you? Also, have you looked into lightning:datatable? It's designed to be easy to use so you don't have to use SLDS yourself.

Comment: i have created a static table but now  i need to add data to that table.I need to get data from particular object and fields and fill the data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Data in salesforce resides in server.
So you either have to make a server call or use `force:recordData` to fetch data without any apex logic.

Here is a sample with a object named as `ARecord__c`. But `force:recordData` will fetch data only with one record at a time.

```
<aura:component implements="force:hasRecordId,flexipage:availableForRecordHome">
    <aura:attribute name="aRecord" type="Object"/>
    <aura:attribute name="recordLoadError" type="String"/>

    <force:recordData aura:id="recordLoader"
                      recordId="{!v.recordId}"
                      fields="Name,Id"
                      targetFields="{!v.aRecord}"
                      targetError="{!v.recordLoadError}"
    />

    <div>
        <lightning:card iconName="standard:account" title="{!v.aRecord.Name}">
            <table class="slds-table slds-table_cell-buffer slds-table_bordered slds-table_col-bordered"
                   aria-label="Example table of Opportunities with vertical borders">
                <thead>
                <tr class="slds-line-height_reset">
                    <th class="" scope="col">
                        <div class="slds-truncate" title="Applicant ID">ARecordId</div>
                    </th>
                    <th class="" scope="col">
                        <div class="slds-truncate" title="ARecord(Name)">ARecord Name
                        </div>
                    </th>
                </tr>
                </thead>
                <tbody>
                <tr class="slds-hint-parent">
                    <td data-label="Applicant ID">
                        <div class="slds-truncate">{!v.aRecord.Id}</div>
                    </td>
                    <td data-label="ARecord(Name)">
                        <div class="slds-truncate">{!v.aRecord.Name}</div>
                    </td>
                </tr>
                </tbody>
            </table>
        </lightning:card>
    </div>
</aura:component>
```

The UI looks like this:

[image]

Comment: Its working and thank you for the response.

Comment: Hai Nagendra singh is it possible to call multiple objects  in this code.

Comment: No you cannot. As `recordId` takes in one record id at a time.

Comment: is there any alternative for this to get multiple objects data?

Comment: The only alternative way is to fire an Apex call from Aura.

Comment: thank you so much. If there any sample code for that please share thank you in advance.